# Pass data to Word 2013 Template

Tags: ms-office, office-interop

I am wondering if it is possible to pass data from an ASP.NET MVC controller to Microsoft Word 2013 Template, using an instantiated Host Item, and bind it to content controls within the template.

Ideally I would like to pass the data to the `ThisDocument` class and have the data applied to the template's databindings, however I cannot find how to instantiate and use the `ThisDocument` object after I have created an interop instance of the Word template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. You can read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

Consider using the Open XML SDK, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) for more information. Or any other third-party components designed for the server-side execution.